# I use caffe to train FCNs for semantic segmentation task, but always get all background result, why?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, image-segmentation

I'm using caffe to **train FCNs8** for semantic segmentation task on pascal voc 2012 dataset **from scratc**h, the train_val prototxt is given by caffe model zoo, 
but no matter how I tried, adjust learning rate try other learning method, I always g**et the zero labels for all pixel which stand for background.** 
The output is all zero which stand for background
Have anyone meet this problem when you are **training a segmentation network from scratch?**
I also try to train other segmentation networks, such as ParseNet, SegNet from scratch, but the result are also all zero.
I trained on pascal voc2012 as well as augmented pascal dataset.

Comment: How are you creating your labels?

Comment: I have tried original images and lmdb. Since pascal voc's segmentation class label images contain 255 for boundries and some train or val images's   size is less than 224, so I change all 255 to 0, and resize the small images whose minimal size is less than 224 to 224 and keep ratio

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. You're talking about two different things here. Size of the image and the label values are two unrelated things. Your problem is with the labels. The pascal voc has a total of 21 classes including the background. The background pixels are labeled with intensity value 0. The other classes, starting from aeroplane, are labeled as 1,2,3 and so on, till 20, in alphabetical order. The boundaries are unclassified and are labelled as 255. they are ignored by the network. Now pixel values 0 to 20 will all appear black to you but they have non-zero values.

Comment: Yes, you are right. As you have mentioned, I thing my labels are correct. My problem is that the network is very easily converge to all zero labels. I use VGG are initialization parameters and filler the new layers with 'xavier' initializations. But during my training, after about 100 or less steps, the network will quick converge to all zero for max final scoremap. Have you ever meet some problem like this ?  which always quickly converge to a local minima?

Comment: Can you share your code for LMDB creation and network initialization and training?

Comment: have you tackle your problem. I meet the same problem as you. I find that if you train a FCN based with pretrained model, you can get a right result, but it is hard to get the same performance by training FCN with initialization parameters.